# Switching from a JPG with a YouTube video

Tags: javascript, html

I have a 940x520px JPG on my webpage inside of a DIV and I would like to make it a link so when you click on it a YouTube video of 940x520px replaces the JPG and automatically starts playing.

What would be the best way of using Javascript to make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="image">
    <img class="img" />
</div>
<div class="youtube" style="display:none;">
    <!--Youtube code here-->
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".img").click(function () {
            $(".image").hide();
            $(".youtube").show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the code, I just copied that and when you click nothing happens.

Answer (score 3):

Use an [onClick](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/event2.shtml) (or [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) if you are using jQuery) to repalce the image with the code for the embedded youtube player.